# Proper name for a method that sets a property but also sends a request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hopefully, this won't be a silly question.

Assume I have the following model:

```
var Appointment = Backbone.Model.extend({

  urlRoot: '/appointments',

  defaults: function() {
    return {
      'Date': new Date(),
      'Status': AppointmentStatus.UPCOMING
    };
  }
});
```

I want to add a method to `Appointment` that is purely for updating the `Status`. This method would do the following:

```
function(newStatus) {
  $.ajax(this.url() + '/status', {
    data: { status: newStatus },
    type: 'POST',
    success: _.bind(function () {
      this.set('Status', newStatus);
    }, this);
  });
}
```

The difficult part is determining a semantically correct name for this method. Should it be `setStatus`, `updateStatus`, or something else? I'd like the name to be easily differentiated from a regular `set` (which is why `setStatus` seems wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you, "updateStatus" makes the most sense to me - it more accurately communicates that there is more involved in its operation than just setting a variable somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. You were first. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You said the answer yourself "...purely for **updating** the Status." It's a silly question but I think you should go ahead with `updateStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

updateStatus more accurately portrays the method than setStatus, especially since it's making an ajax request and all. I would reserve names like setStatus for when you're initializing something.